# Need to set up Tomcat and JSF on an ubuntu machine

Tags: java, webserver, tomcat

As the title says, I need to set up Tomcat and JSF on an ubuntu machine, and seem to be running into issues because the tutorials i find online are out of date. Can someone provide an up-to-date tutorial, or provide me with some simple steps? I already have the tomcat6 package installed using apt-get install, but am totally lost from here. I will first be testing on my local machine, and then eventually using it on my server, so security and best practice advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

These should be able to help you out.
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/index.html - Official Documentation
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Securing_tomcat - This is for Tomcat5.5 but still helps you get an idea.